# While looping statements

Tags: php, sql, database

Here is my code block

```
</tr>
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="aabbcc"><center>Line 1</td>
    <?php
    //Connect to mysql server
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'User', 'Pass', 'Database');
    if (!$con) {
        die ("connection error". mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    $results = mysqli_query($con, " SELECT * FROM PMAsset where     LineNum='1' Order by Linenum, LineOrder ") or die(mysqli_error($con));
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
        ?>
        <td Bgcolor=<?php echo $row['PMStatus']?>>Line <?php echo     $row['LineNum']?> PM <?php echo $row['LineOrder']?></td>

        <?php
    }
    ?>
</tr>
```

What I am trying to do is create a table row that populates the data there are 10 columns in the row I attached a pic of what I get currently.

[image: Image of generated table]

As you can see Its not looping the 10 times. what do I need to do to make this happen. I'm confused on the building the loop. And from the pic Line 3 should be under the Line 3 PM3. I understand why it works that way. however, How do I put it in the correct cell and change the boxes black if there is no data to go there? Any and all help would be great. Here is the database table

[image: Image of database table]

```
<center>
<table border="1" Width="80%">
  <tr bgcolor="5DF588">
    <th>Line Number</th>
    <th>PM 1</th>
    <th>PM 2</th>
    <th>PM 3</th>
    <th>PM 4</th>
    <th>PM 5</th>
    <th>PM 6</th>
    <th>PM 7</th>
    <th>PM 8</th>
    <th>PM 9</th>
    <th>PM 10</th>
  </tr>
               <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="aabbcc"><center>Line 1</td>
                     <td Bgcolor=Red>Line 1 PM 1</td>
                     <td Bgcolor=green>Line 1 PM 2</td>
                     <td Bgcolor=Yellow>Line 1 PM 3</td>
                     <td Bgcolor=Green>Line 1 PM 4</td>
 </tr>
               <tr>
        <td bgcolor="E5F29D"><center>Line 2</td>
                <td Bgcolor=Red>Line 2 PM 2</td>
</tr>
             <tr>
        <td bgcolor="aabbcc"><center>Line 3</td>
                <td Bgcolor=Yellow>Line 3 PM 3</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Can you also show us what HTML is being generated, by inspecting source or by viewing page source please. 
And also I do want to add, that since you are wanting to loop 10 times for the ten columns, you probably should loop using for loop, so that can you can display an empty cell if there is no value.

Comment: tHIS IS THAT SECTION OF VIEW SOURSE

Answer (score 0):

Oh I see, why don't you create a function to which you can pass the linenumber and lineorder and run a query for the given linenumber and lineorder. The function can therefore return the null or value from the database and you can use that to populate the cells by looping through a for loop .

Function can be something like this:

```
function getcell($linenumber, $lineorder){
  global $con;
  $r = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM PMAsset where LineNum='$linenumber' AND `LineOrder` = '$lineorder' LIMIT 1") or die(mysqli_error($con));

  if( $r->num_rows == 1){
    $row = $r->fetch_assoc();
    return '<td> ... HTML HERE .. </td>';
  } else {
    return '<td> &nbsp; </td>';
  } 
}
```

And you can loop through each linenum and lineorder using nested for loops for better control. 
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know is how many elements you've output and pad it with the remaining slots.

```
$col = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
    ?>
    <td Bgcolor=<?php echo $row['PMStatus']?>>Line <?php echo     $row['LineNum']?> PM <?php echo $row['LineOrder']?></td>

    <?php
    $col++;
}
while ($col++ < 10) {
   echo '<td />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do another approach.
You could try to save all your data in a 2-dimensional array and then loop over it.

Save your data in an 2-dimensional array:

```
// your new array
$data = [];

$sql = "
    SELECT * FROM PMAsset 
        ORDER BY Linenum, LineOrder
;";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));

while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result ) ) {

    // use the LineNum and LineOrder as Keys
    $data[ $row[LineNum] ][ $row[LineOrder] ] = $row['PMStatus'];    

}
```

You have now the full data in the array and cana loop for your 10 columns and lines:

```
... your table head    

// loop LINENUMBERS -> $ln
for( $ln = 1; $ln < 10; $ln++ ) {

    // loop LineOrder -> $lo
    for( $lo = 1; $lo < 10; $lo++ ) {

        echo "<tr>";

        if( isset( $data[$ln][$lo] ) {

            // key exists and is not empty or NULL
            echo "<td Bgcolor=\"{$data[$ln][$lo]}\"> Line {$ln} PM {$lo}  </td>";

        } else {

            // key does not exists
            echo "<td>no data</td>";

        }

    }

    echo "</tr>";

}
...
```

Hope the code is clear. Let me know.

Comment: $sql = " SELECT * FROM PMAsset ORDER BY Linenum, LineOrder";
 $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));
     while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result ) ) {
?>
}
// loop LINENUMBERS -> $ln
for( $ln = 1; $ln < 10; $ln++ ){

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td Bgcolor=<?php echo $row['PMStatus']?>>Line <?php echo $row['LineNum']?> PM <?php echo $row['LineOrder']?></td>";
        } else {
            // Color Black
            echo "<td Bgcolor="000000"><?php echo $row['AssetNum']?></td>";
        }
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}

Comment: Is this your working solution? It's hard to read in the comments

Comment: I'm not sure if I read it correctly out, but you can get in trouble if one line is  missing. Like line1 data line2 no data etc.